# Python Pandas, converting datetime data into datetime.utc. whilst ignoring the timezones

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, utc

I have a pandas dataframe with the following data:

```
    PointId      Time                  Value
0  Brabrand1_1  2020-10-02 23:58:14+02  0.9754
1  Brabrand1_1  2020-02-23 21:03:00+01  2.1414
2  Brabrand1_1  2020-02-23 21:33:00+01  2.1406
3  Brabrand1_1  2019-01-29 18:03:32+01  1.0390
4  Brabrand1_1  2019-01-29 18:33:32+01  1.0390
5  Brabrand1_1  2019-01-29 19:03:32+01  1.0390
6  Brabrand1_1  2019-01-29 19:33:32+01  1.0399
7  Brabrand1_1  2019-01-29 20:03:32+02  1.0000
```

I want the Time data to be UTC, ignoring the +01, +02 ... whats a good
way of removing the +01 or +02... is it best to convert to string and remove
or is there a more appropirate way of converting to datetime and then
converting to utc?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can change the time zone without changing the time with:

```
import dateutil.tz

new_datetime = old_datetime.replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzutc())
```

For your dataframe, you can use:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda old_datetime: old_datetime.replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzutc()))
```

If you are using python 3.9, you can use `zoneinfo` instead of `dateutil.tz`. You should avoid using `pytz`, although it wouldn't cause any problems in this situation.

https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html

Comment: Thanks for the help, out of curiocity why should I not use pytz?

Comment: This link explains the problem with pytz. The time zone needs to know the date before the offset can be calculated correctly, but if you use pytz in the datetime constructor, it will compute the offset before it knows the date.
https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html

Comment: Thanks thats really helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your data to be in UTC:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.tz_convert('UTC')
```

If you want to remove tzinfo:

```
df['Time'].dt.tz_localize(None)
```

So to drop tzinfo and convert to UTC:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.tz_localize(None).dt.tz_convert('UTC')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I used what you people said and had to dig a bit more but got the answer by doing this:

```
df['Time'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['Time'], utc=True)
df.Time.dt.tz_convert('UTC')
```